# jQuery How to iterate through autocomplete and set title and display it on hover

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

How can i loop through a dynamic list created by jquery autocomplete plugin...
i need to loop through each element in the list and set the title of each value listed in the menu...the title should be the same name as the product name...

the reason for doing this is because some text in the list is hidden using

**overflow:hidden;** style...

so when the user hovers over any element the javascript has to set the current name of the product to the tile attribute..so that when hovering it display the full product name...

How can i do this....

the code so far i tried,

```
         jQuery.each(availableTags, function(index,value) {
             this.attr().title = document.getElementById("#").innerHtml;
         });
```

and this,

```
         jQuery.each("#autocompid", function(index,value) {
             var value = $(this).val();
             $("#autocompid ul li").attr(title,value));
         });
```

and my autocomplete like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/fewds/HwchC/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code after your autocomplete was bind

```
$("#autocompid").data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append($("<a/>").html(item.label).attr("title", item.label))
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
```

_renderItem is a function of autocomplete plugin and we are overriding that function here.

Comment: well when you bind an autocomplete with any textbox, $.autocomplete plugin adds "autocomplete" data with that text box. if you can look at aucoomplete plugin, _renderItem() is called everytime your result is populated in autocomplete. since we are overloading this function so every time your list will be populated, this function will be called hence you can do whatever you want to do with every item/list item of the complete before it renders.

Comment: Also its a general recommendation that, you should do as minimum as possible operation while working on autocomplete, since user expects results as soon as he enters anything in textbox, and if you are doing alot of operation before even it renders, it can make the rendering a bit slow.

Comment: It is not overloading, but overriding the function.